# How to display a large series of images to the map with a for loop in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I need to view imagery from a collection as separate layers. Since I have to do this for several sites and the number of images in the collection therefore varies, I tried to apply a for loop to solve this.

My working code without for loop looks like this:

```
// Load a landsat image and select three bands for Mount Spurr

// HSV-based Pan-Sharpening of Landsat 7 TOA images.
var panSharpenL8 = function(image) {
  var rgb = image.select('B3', 'B2', 'B1');
  var pan = image.select('B8');
  // Convert to HSV, swap in the pan band, and convert back to RGB.
  var huesat = rgb.rgbToHsv().select('hue', 'saturation');
  var upres = ee.Image.cat(huesat, pan).hsvToRgb();
  return image.addBands(upres);
};


var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_TOA')
                  .filterDate('2004-04-01', '2006-06-30')
                  .sort('system:time_start')
                  .map(panSharpenL8)


// short form
var Image_filtered = dataset.filterBounds(geometry_Mount_Spurr)
.filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than',10)
print(Image_filtered.size())

var listOfImages = Image_filtered.toList(Image_filtered.size());
print('List:',listOfImages);

var img1 = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(0));
var img2 = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(1));
var img3 = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(2));
var img4 = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(3));
var img5 = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(4));
var img6 = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(5));
var img7 = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(6));
var img8 = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(7));
var img9 = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(8));
var img10 = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(9));
var img11 = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(10));
var img12 = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(11));
var img13 = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(12));
var img14 = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(13));
var img15 = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(14));
var img16 = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(15));
var img17 = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(16));
var img18 = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(17));

// add pansharpened bands

Map.addLayer(img1, {bands:['red','green','blue'], max: 0.3}, 'Pansharpened');
Map.addLayer(img2, {bands:['red','green','blue'], max: 0.3}, 'Pansharpened');
Map.addLayer(img3, {bands:['red','green','blue'], max: 0.3}, 'Pansharpened');
Map.addLayer(img4, {bands:['red','green','blue'], max: 0.3}, 'Pansharpened');
Map.addLayer(img5, {bands:['red','green','blue'], max: 0.3}, 'Pansharpened');
Map.addLayer(img6, {bands:['red','green','blue'], max: 0.3}, 'Pansharpened');
Map.addLayer(img7, {bands:['red','green','blue'], max: 0.3}, 'Pansharpened');
Map.addLayer(img8, {bands:['red','green','blue'], max: 0.3}, 'Pansharpened');
Map.addLayer(img9, {bands:['red','green','blue'], max: 0.3}, 'Pansharpened');
Map.addLayer(img10, {bands:['red','green','blue'], max: 0.3}, 'Pansharpened');
Map.addLayer(img11, {bands:['red','green','blue'], max: 0.3}, 'Pansharpened');
Map.addLayer(img12, {bands:['red','green','blue'], max: 0.3}, 'Pansharpened');
Map.addLayer(img13, {bands:['red','green','blue'], max: 0.3}, 'Pansharpened');
Map.addLayer(img14, {bands:['red','green','blue'], max: 0.3}, 'Pansharpened');
Map.addLayer(img15, {bands:['red','green','blue'], max: 0.3}, 'Pansharpened');
Map.addLayer(img16, {bands:['red','green','blue'], max: 0.3}, 'Pansharpened');
Map.addLayer(img17, {bands:['red','green','blue'], max: 0.3}, 'Pansharpened');
Map.addLayer(img18, {bands:['red','green','blue'], max: 0.3}, 'Pansharpened');



//Map.addLayer(Image_filtered, {bands:['red','green','blue'], max: 0.3}, 'Pansharpened');
```

As you can see, there are many `Map.addLayer` expressions. I wish to not copy and paste the lines to add each image to the Map, so I built an `ee.List` and looped like this:

```
var listOfImages = ee.List(Image_filtered);
print('List:',listOfImages);

var len = listOfImages.length;

for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
  var img = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(i));
  Map.addLayer(img, {bands:['red','green','blue'], max: 0.3}, 'Pansharpened');
}
```

However, it does not add layers to the map and does not result in an error message.

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `listOfImages` variable is a server-side `ee.List` object and has no `length` property (`length` is a property of a client-side JS list object), so when you use it to define the `len` variable it produces a function, which likely results in a null value when you try to use it to bound the for loop.

What you need to do is use `.size()` on the `listOfImages` variable and then convert the result to a client-side object for bounding the for loop. Use the `.evaluate()` method to safely convert server-side objects to client-side objects.

```js
// Get the size of the image list (this is a server side ee.Number object).
var len = listOfImages.size();

// Call `.evaluate()` on `len` to convert it from server-side object to a
// client-side object available within the scope of the anonymous function as `l`.
len.evaluate(function(l) {
  for (var i=0; i < l; i++) {
    var img = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(i));
    Map.addLayer(img, {bands:['red','green','blue'], max: 0.3}, 'Img-'+i.toString());
  } 
});
```

Please see the [Client vs. Server](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server) section of the Developer Guide for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much! You solved my problem! If I am right, the problem was, that I tried to execute the for loop on the client-side, but the object to iterate on was server-side... However, I am wondering, why ee.List.length() is listed in the google earth engine Docs!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you! Your assessment of the problem is correct: mixing server-side objects with client-side operations. You are right about `.length()` being a method of `ee.List` objects. What I intended to say was "property" instead of "method". Your use of `.length` is intended for client-side JS objects - it fetches the "length" property of the object through dot notation, but an `ee.List` object has no such property (at least not accessible through JS object dot notation). I've updated my answer to clarify this.

Comment: Ok, this makes it more clear, thanks!