# Unable to do Map.addLayer() for all images in an ImageCollection in GEE

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I found this code 
[Add/display all images of mycollection in google earth engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/284610/add-display-all-images-of-mycollection-in-google-earth-engine)
and tried it, but the output displays four layers each with one band called constant.

Also, can you please tell me what is to be given as `image.id` - do I have to set any property in it?

My code is below. Note that `collectYear` is my image collection. How should I proceed?

```
geometry = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[76.15934177863937, 9.45738504612055],
      [76.85697361457687, 9.45738504612055],
      [76.85148045051437, 9.993390779673321],
      [76.14011570442062, 9.990685858146769]]]);
function maskS2clouds(image) {
var qa = image.select('QA60');

// Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

// Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
  .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}


var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2');
var years = ee.List.sequence(2016, 2018);
print (years);

var collectYear = ee.ImageCollection(years
.map(function(y) {
var start = ee.Date.fromYMD(y, 1, 1);
var end = start.advance(12, 'month');
var d2 =  dataset.filterDate(start, end).filterBounds(geometry)
              // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
              .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 10))
              .map(maskS2clouds).first();

//Applying clip to image 
var ls_clipped = ee.Image(d2).clip(geometry);
var resamp_img = ls_clipped.resample('bilinear');
var B2_B11 = resamp_img.select('B2').divide(resamp_img.select('B11'));
var ratio_image = resamp_img.addBands(B2_B11);
return ratio_image;
}));
print(collectYear);

function addImage(image) { // display each image in collection
var id = image.id;
var image = ee.Image(image.id)
Map.addLayer(image);
}

collectYear.evaluate(function(collectYear) {  // use map on client-side
collectYear.features.map(addImage);
});
```

Comment: Please provide a link to a functioning EE script, with all used assets shared.

Comment: i am quite new to this... i am not able to create a URL that works for others .. i am pasting the code though in the question .. please find it.

Comment: Hi @rao, to share scripts via Code Editor URLs, just click the "Get Link" at the top of the code editor panel. A dialog box will appear providing a "copy link" button (the URL is also automatically added to the clipboard).

Comment: Related question and answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/348061/68792

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just loop over your years client-side and add them to the map. To make this easier, you might want to set the year as a property of each image.

```
var startYear = 2016
var endYear = 2018
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2');
var years = ee.List.sequence(startYear, endYear);
print(years);

var collectYear = ee.ImageCollection(years
  .map(function(y) {
    var start = ee.Date.fromYMD(y, 1, 1);
    var end = start.advance(12, 'month');
    var d2 = dataset.filterDate(start, end).filterBounds(geometry)
      // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
      .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 10))
      .map(maskS2clouds).first();

    //Applying clip to image 
    var ls_clipped = ee.Image(d2).clip(geometry);
    var resamp_img = ls_clipped.resample('bilinear');
    var B2_B11 = resamp_img.select('B2').divide(resamp_img.select('B11'));
    var ratio_image = resamp_img.addBands(B2_B11);
    return ratio_image
      .set('year', y)
  }));
print(collectYear);

function addImage(image) { // display each image in collection
  var id = image.id;
  Map.addLayer(image);
}

for (var year = startYear; year <= endYear; year++) {
  var image = collectYear
    .filterMetadata('year', 'equals', year)
    .first()
  var visParams = {bands: 'B4,B3,B2', min: 0.03, max: 0.3, gamma: 1.5}
  Map.addLayer(image, visParams, '' + year)
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/5239181e2b7ac82e3377faa00dade9c1