# Can't visualize ImageCollection using Map.addLayer()

Tags: google-earth-engine

I was trying to retrieving chlorophyll-a levels using Landsat9. After processed it using this function :

```
 //Clorophyll-a Levels
 // Coefficients
 var a0= 0.341
 var a1= -3.001
 var a2= 2.811
 var a3= -2.041
 var a4= 0.0400

function R(img){
return img.expression(
      'log10(blue/green)',
      {
        'blue': img.select('B2'),
        'green': img.select('B3')
      });
}

var Ratio = citra.map(R)

function chlor(img){
return img.expression(
      '10**(a0+a1*R+a2*R**2+a3*R**3)+a4',
      {
        'a0': a0,
        'a1': a1,
        'a2': a2,
        'a3': a3,
        'a4': a4,
        'R': Ratio
      })
}

var chl = citra.map(chlor)

var ChlVisPar = {min:0.4,max:1.5,palette:['blue','lime','yellow','orange','red']}
Map.addLayer(chl,ChlVisPar,'Chlor-a')
```

I cant visualize using the `Map.addLayer(chla,ChlVisPar,'Chlor-a')` and I got messages:

> Layer error: Image.pow, argument 'image1': Invalid type.
> Expected type: Image.
> Actual type: ImageCollection.

How do I solve this?

Comment: The error is clear. You are trying to add an ImageCollection when an Image is expected. You either have to choose an image from the collection to show (e.g. `chl.first()` or use `chl.get(index)`. Or make an aggregation (e.g. `chl.median()`). 

If you want to show every image in the collection as a layer you can use an approach such as [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/348258/128665) but map over indices up to the collection length, rather than the year.

Comment: Previously, I had done similar processing with a dataset in the form of images with expression features. However, I cannot carry out the cloudmasking process using the QA_PIXEL band along with other features such as bitwise.

therefore I tried to recreate it by processing the imagecollection using a function.
Is it possible if I can change the processing results into images, or how do I clip images in the first processing with AOI imagecollection which I have cloudmasked?

Answer (score 0):

The error is not because you're trying to add an `ee.ImageCollection` to the Map. Actually, when you do that, the function adds a mosaic of all images inside the collection, and the inspector shows the values of each image as a series.

So, before adding each individual image into the Map, you need to fix the error.

The method `ee.ImageCollection.map` returns an `ee.ImageCollection`, thus the variable `Ratio` is of that type. In the function `chlor` you're trying to use `Ratio` as a variable in the expression, but you can only use `ee.Image`

This is how I'd solve it:

```
function R(img){
  return img.expression(
        'log10(blue/green)',
        {
          'blue': img.select('B2'),
          'green': img.select('B3')
        });
}

function chlor(img){
  var r = R(img)
  return ee.Image().expression(
        '10**(a0+a1*R+a2*R**2+a3*R**3)+a4',
        {
          'a0': a0,
          'a1': a1,
          'a2': a2,
          'a3': a3,
          'a4': a4,
          'R': r
        })
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/eea2a43e47f2f84e8d67d624bbf37cf9

Then, you can add each image on the Map using different techniques. This is what I would do:

```
var addIC = function(col, property) {
  // choose a property to use as filter and img name
  property = property || "system:index"
  // fetch all values for that property
  var allProp = col.aggregate_array(property).getInfo()
  // loop over each value of the property
  for (var i in allProp) {
    var prop = allProp[i]
    // filter the IC with the property value and get one image
    var i = col.filter(ee.Filter.eq(property, prop)).first()
    // add to map
    Map.addLayer(i, ChlVisPar, prop)
  }
}

addIC(chl)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/28690cc4e4334673d27163b2954d4870